# Reading a file in an async context?

Tags: asynchronous, io, f#

I would like to leverage `async` to make my code more readable and performant in F#.

I can read an entire file with a function like this:

```
let readFile path = async {
  return System.IO.File.ReadAllText path
}
```

And then use the function like this:

```
"README.md" |> readFile |> Async.RunSynchronously |> Console.WriteLine
```

However, the .NET `ReadAllText` method is blocking.

Is this an appropriate way to read files using `async`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `StreamReader` class which exposes an asynchronous version of `ReadToEnd`.

```
let readFile (path:string) = async {
  use sr = new StreamReader(path)
  return! sr.ReadToEndAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
}
```

In practice, it is probably a good idea to run some measurements to make sure that you are actually getting some benefits from using async in this scenario - unless you are doing something interesting with many files, it might not matter much.

---

Bonus:

```ml
let writeFile (path : string) (content : string) = async {
  use sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path)
  return!
    sw.WriteAsync(content)
    |> Async.AwaitTask
}
```

Comment: `StreamReader` is `IDisposable` so should it be `use` instead of `let`?

Comment: @sdgfsdh You're right, thanks! I fixed that in the answer.